# A sleep button shows up on my Mac recently, how to get rid of it?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sleep-wake

I'm not sure what happened, but recently I found I have this button showing up.  Does anyone know how to turn it off?

- OS: 10.15.3 (19D76) Catalina
- MacBook Pro 13inch, 2017, 4 Thunderbolt 3 Ports
- Memory: 16GB
- 3.5Ghz

[image: sleep button]

Comment: "Shows up" where? Give details about your problem. This is very very vague.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have enabled the Dictation or Voice Control features.

You can disable it again by opening System Preferences > Keyboard. Select the "Dictation" tab, and ensure it is set to "Off".

Then open System Preferences > Accessibility. Select "Voice Control" (or "VoiceOver" in earlier versions) in the list on the left, and ensure that "Enable VoiceOver" is *not* selected.

Comment: My setting is off, not sure why this is still showing up

Comment: Turn Dictation on, then turn it off. Sometimes a setting gets 'stuck' and doing a on/off toggle resets it. System Preferences > Accessibility has a Dictation pane under the Interaction section. Perhaps something is set in that pane?

Answer (score 2):

After some research, looks like this is called Voice Control in macOS.  This is how we can disable it

On your Mac, choose Apple menu  > System Preferences, click Accessibility, then click Voice Control. De-select "Enable VoiceOver".

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/control-your-mac-and-apps-using-voice-control-mh40719/mac